# c# detect the line current text is on?

Tags: c#

I'd like to detect what line a text is on in the console application.

My intent is to adjust the scroll to -1 of where some text lies.

```
Console.SetWindowPosition(0,currentLineNumber-1);
```

Any ideas?

To further explain my intent: I'm creating a sort of chat-bot and I don't want chat history to be cleared, so instead I'm aiming to have the scroll-bar move the text to the top of the screen every time the bot begins a line of dialogue.

Comment: Is CMD what we're talking about? Also, What have you tried/researched before asking here?

Comment: Is [`Console.CursorTop`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.console.cursortop) or [`Console.WindowTop`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.console.windowtop) what you're looking for?

Comment: I'd found something that works but only if you log as each line goes, which seems to me as inefficient. I wondered if there's a cleaner way to detect what line you're on.

Comment: is it because you intend to create an animation during an action? I think describing more in detail what your application would do could be helpful in this scenario

Comment: I added more to the question, I hope that helps @Icepickle